# Tracking 2D coordinates in a 3D space

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, virtual-reality, openvr

I am working on a gesture tracking feature for a virtual reality game I am working on. I need to keep track of the players hand coordinates to check them against a existing gesture. I only want to track on the X and Y. My Problem is taking the 3D coordinates and making them 2D. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What kind of devices are you working with? Are you using xbox's kinect or are you using a camera and building everything from scratch?

Comment: So do you want to convert 3D world-space coordinates to 2D screen-space coordinates? if that's what you want then you can use u = x / z;
v = y / z;

Comment: @RinaldiSegecin I am using the Oculus Rift with touch controllers.

Comment: @Asesh Thanks. That should work!